# Raspberry Pi Wifi Access Point behind Proxy

Tags: wifi

I am behind a Proxy on our network, which requires username and pwd in order to browse internet.

This causes problems with certain applications having to access internet pages if the application does not support proxy authentication.

1. I have successfully configured my Pi3 to browse the internet through the proxy via Ethernet
2. I have successfully configured my Pi3 to be a WiFi Access point

Is it possible to configure the Pi3 to route all Wifi-client http data without having these clients to proxy authenticate?

Comment: You should be able to configure iptables (the kernel firewall) to [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) tcp packets with destination port 80 or 8080 to your proxy using the DNAT target: http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-targets-and-jumps.html#DNATTARGET  This works below the application level so affects everything.